# How to recreate a copy of a product category in WooCommerce?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to make a copy of a category with its subcategories. Because I need dozens of the same category. How can i do this?

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you want to apply the same categories to multiple Posts or Products? Than you can use the bulk edit feature of wordpress.

Comment: Let's think a category. A category named Volvo S60 and its subcategories tehcnical, news etc. My point is to duplicate this category and change only its parent category name. Because I need dozens of the same structure and making this manually requires very effort.

Comment: So you want to create sub categories via script and link them to parent categories via api? You can use the wp_insert_term function. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/

Comment: Instead of going from specific to general, would starting with general and going more specific save you a lot of very similar category names?